# Div width expanding despite using white-space: pre-wrap;

Tags: html, css

Each time text is added to the #output and jscode (and other code) pre tags, the divs expand to fit the text on one line. How can I ensure that when text is added to these elements that they wrap properly keeping the original div widths as they were?

```css
  #output {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #282c34;
  /* Dark background color */
  color: #ffffff;
  /* Light text color */
  padding: 15px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* Preserve spaces and line breaks */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Break words at any character */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Include padding and border in the element's total width and height */
}

#jscode,
#pycode,
#luacode,
#dartcode,
#phpcode {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #282c34;
  /* Dark background color */
  color: #abb2bf;
  /* Light text color */
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
  /* Monospace font */
  padding: 15px;
  /* Add some padding */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* Preserve spaces and line breaks */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Break words at any character */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Include padding and border in the element's total width and height */
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 80vh;">
  <div id="blocklyArea" style="flex: 0 0 60%;"></div>
  <div id="blocklyDiv" style="position: absolute;"></div>
  <div id="rightContainer" style="flex: 0 0 40%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div id="output" style="flex: 0 0 60%; overflow: auto;"></div>
    <div id="bottomContainer" style="flex: 0 0 40%; position: relative; overflow: auto;">
      <div class="tabsContainer" style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('jscode')">JavaScript</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('pycode')">Python</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('luacode')">Lua</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('dartcode')">Dart</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('phpcode')">PHP</button>
      </div>
      <div id="jscode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <pre id="jscodePre"></pre>
      </div>
      <div id="pycode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <pre id="pycodePre"></pre>
      </div>
      <div id="luacode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <pre id="luacodePre"></pre>
      </div>
      <div id="dartcode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <pre id="dartcodePre"></pre>
      </div>
      <div id="phpcode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <pre id="phpcodePre"></pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but your code is very dirty. I'm assuming you're adding some text to the `pre` elements and want it to wrap. Because that's exactly what you set for the parent element (`#jscode`). So these properties should also be added to the `pre` element:

```css
#output {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #282c34;
  /* Dark background color */
  color: #ffffff;
  /* Light text color */
  padding: 15px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* Preserve spaces and line breaks */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Break words at any character */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Include padding and border in the element's total width and height */
}

#jscode,
#pycode,
#luacode,
#dartcode,
#phpcode {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #282c34;
  /* Dark background color */
  color: #abb2bf;
  /* Light text color */
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
  /* Monospace font */
  padding: 15px;
  /* Add some padding */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* Preserve spaces and line breaks */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Break words at any character */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Include padding and border in the element's total width and height */
 }
 pre{
   /*  */
  white-space: inherit;
  word-break: inherit;
 }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 80vh;">
  <div id="blocklyArea" style="flex: 0 0 60%;"></div>
  <div id="blocklyDiv" style="position: absolute;"></div>
  <div id="rightContainer" style="flex: 0 0 40%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div id="output" style="flex: 0 0 60%; overflow: auto;"></div>
    <div id="bottomContainer" style="flex: 0 0 40%; position: relative; overflow: auto;">
      <div class="tabsContainer" style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('jscode')">JavaScript</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('pycode')">Python</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('luacode')">Lua</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('dartcode')">Dart</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('phpcode')">PHP</button>
      </div>
      <div id="jscode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <pre id="jscodePre">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</pre>
      </div>
      <div id="pycode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <pre id="pycodePre"></pre>
      </div>
      <div id="luacode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <pre id="luacodePre"></pre>
      </div>
      <div id="dartcode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <pre id="dartcodePre"></pre>
      </div>
      <div id="phpcode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <pre id="phpcodePre"></pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```